# What's wrong in this recurrence?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, recurrence

Problem statement :

> One day Blue Mary goes to a nearby supermarket to buy some goods. She
>   has a backpack, whose capacity is V-Max. She finds that there are many
>   goods in the market, each has a volume Vi(it will always be a multiple
>   of 10 and less than 10000) and an importance Ci(1<= Ci <=5). Since she
>   has almost unlimited money, the only problem she is to solve is how to
>   choose goods such that the total volume won't exceed the capacity of
>   the backpack and the sum of the product of the volume and the
>   importance of each good is maximum. To be an excellent mathematician,
>   she comes up with the answer quickly, and now she wants you to do a
>   harder task. There are two kinds of goods: main goods and attachments.
>   If you want to buy an attachment you must buy its main good before.
>
> Input
>
> Multiple test cases, the number of them is given in the very first
>   line.
>
> For each test case:
>
> The first line contains two space-separated integers V-Max
>   (1<=V-Max<=32000) and the number of the goods N (1<=N<=60). N lines
>   follow, each contains three space-separated integers Vi, Ci and a
>   integer u. If u is not 0, this good is an attachment of good u(as the
>   order in the input file).
>
> To make the problem not too difficult, Blue Mary tells you that:
>
> (A) An attachment won't have any attachments which belong to it.
>
> (B) A main good will always have less than 3 attachments.
>
> Output
>
> For each test case:
>
> The first and the only line contains a single integer denoted the
>   answer.
>
> Example
>
> Input: 1 1000 5 800 2 0 400 5 1 300 5 1 400 3 0 500 2 0
>
> Output: 2200

My backtrack solution :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
multimap<int,pair<int,int>>data; //to store attachments

int wt[61],val[61];//to store main goods

int solve(int n,int vol){
if(n<1||vol<0||wt[n]>vol)
  return 0;
if(wt[n]==-1)
  return solve(n-1,vol);
int w = wt[n], v = val[n];
int ret = solve(n-1,vol-w)+w*v;
auto range = data.equal_range(n); //check if there are any attachments
int coun = v*w,cw = w;
for(auto i=range.first;i!=range.second;i++){

int w1 = i->second.first,v1= i->second.second;
  coun+=w1*v1;
  cw += w1;
 ret = max(ret,solve(n-1,vol-w-w1)+w*v+w1*v1); //take only this attachment

ret = max(ret,solve(n-1,vol-cw)+coun); //take this attachment along with previous one *there can be only 2 attachments at max*


}
return ret;
}

int main ()
{
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
  int vmax,n;
  cin>>vmax>>n;
  int a,b,c;
  int sz = 1;
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    if(c==0){ //treat this as a main good
      wt[i] = a;
      val[i]=b;

    }else{ //treat this as an attachment
      data.insert(make_pair(c,make_pair(a,b)));
      wt[i] = -1; //this indicates that this index is an attachment
    }
  }

  cout << solve(n,vmax) << endl;
}

}
```

### Explaination :

Details about main goods are stored in arrays(wt[] and val[]) and attachments are stored in  `multimap<int,pair<int,int>>data`. If wt[i] == -1, it means that there is no main good at index i. In function solve(),these cases are checked:

- Just take the main good without any attachment.
- check for attachments
- take the first attachment along with main good (total weight=weight of main good + attachment. value=value of main good + attachment)
- take the second attachment along the main good
- take both the attachments (note : there can only be 2 attachments at max. If this isn't the case the code won't work properly)

I have checked this code on various test cases and its working fine but on submitting this, I'm getting "Wrong Answer" error. Please note that this is a backtrack solution and I've not memoized the code. What's wrong with this solution and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Please supply accurate input/output examples.  The one you give doesn't match the problem specs.  Also, supply your testing plan and data.  Given the lack of feedback, this will be hard enough to diagnose.  I don't expect that anyone will tackle it until you narrow the problem space appropriately.

Comment: @Prune I have added the code description

Comment: That does help.  I'll wait for the rest before tackling this.